# Prototype not used in called RPGLE program , but the program still works

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have a program SS150R where the PI is declared as

```
Dcl-pi SS150R;                        
pCompcd Char(4);                  
ptrncd Packed(3:0);               
pErrMsg Char(30) options(*nopass);
pSuccess Char(1) options(*nopass);
End-pi;
```

There is no prototype (PR) declared for this (PI), but still the program is working fine.

My question is that I have always read that a prototype has to be declared if there is a named PI , if its not a named PI like

```
dcl-pi *n ;
Parm char(1) ;
end-pi ;
```

Then there is no need for the prototype declaration.
Can some one explain in case of my program SS150R there is a named PI and no PR for it , but how is it still working?

Note: My program is called by old Non-RPG program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, prototypes are only used by the compiler to define parameters for a `CALLP` op code. But the compiler is smart enough (since v7.1) that if the procedure is defined within the same source as the `CALLP`, it can get the parameter definitions from the procedure interface. A prototype is not a runtime object, so does not affect the running of a program once it is successfully compiled.

A prototype is really only required if the procedure or program is called by an external program or procedure using `CALLP`. But I usually create prototypes for all `EXPORT`ed procedures and `MAIN` procedures because I will likely want to call them from some other RPGLE program or procedure, and I only use `CALLP` these days.

So here are the various scenarios:

- Procedure called by another procedure in the same source - prototype not needed.
- Procedure or program called by another procedure or program (Not RPGLE) - prototype not needed.
- Program called by OPM program - prototype not needed (not recommended)
- Procedure or program called by another procedure or program (Not using CALLP) - prototype not needed (not recommended)
- Procedure or program called by another procedure or program using CALLP - prototype required.

Just to reiterate, If I am defining a procedure in a module, and that procedure is declared with EXPORT, then I always create a prototype. In addition I always declare a prototype for all program main procedures. These prototypes are always defined in a copy book so the same prototypes can be used in any potential calling program or procedure. I only use `CALLP` these days to call procedures or programs from RPGLE, and that op code is always implicit.

Procedures that are defined without `EXPORT` never require prototypes, so I do not code them.

NOTE: `CALL` and `CALLB` must always be explicitly included, I don't use either of those any more.

Comment: Back in v7.1, IBM relaxed the prototype requirement for "internal" procedures.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I was unsure when that happened. It's been a while ago, and every box I have access to now is 7.2+, so I don't ever need prototypes for non-`EXPORTED` procedures.